# How to change image src within anchor tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace image `src` dynamically based on selected value from the drop down.I have created a custom drop down for my web page.I can set the text successfully but i can not replace `img` `src` with selected value.In my case `img` is inside `anchor<a>` tag.

**HTML Code**

```
  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-9">
 <div class="btn-group">
<a id="browser-text" class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);"><img id="browser-text-img" src="img/safari.png" height="18" width="18"  > Browser</a>
<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
</li>
<li>
<a class="browser" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/iE.png" height="18" width="18"  > IE</a>

</li>
<li>

</li>

<li>
<a class="browser" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/opera.png" height="18" width="18"  > OPERA</a>

</li>

<li>

</ul>
</div><!-- /btn-group --></td>

</div>
</div>
```

**Js Code**

```
//browser on click func


$('a.browser').click( function() { 

      $("#browser-text").text( $(this).text());//this execute successfully.
      $('#browser-text img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); //this nothing happens.
    } );
```

Please let me know how can i replace `browser-text-img` with select image value from drop down.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to get a src of a anchor tag..Then how will it work?

Comment: $(this).children('img').attr('src') perhaps?

Comment: @ Arumuga Raja i want to replace `browser-text-img` src with drop down selected `a img` value.

Comment: Use `$(this).find("img").attr("src")` instead of `$(this).attr("src")`

Comment: but when i put `$("#browser-text").text( $(this).text());` this wont work.how can i set text also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` has `href="javascript:void(0);"` and no information about image.

You have to access it's child image `src`:

```
$('#browser-text img').attr(
    'src',
    $('img', this).attr('src')
);
```

---

You can put `span` wrapper for text and change only that part:

```js
$('a.browser').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#browser-text')
    .find('img')
    .attr('src', $('img', this).attr('src'))
  .end()
    .find('span')
    .text($(this).text())
  ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-9">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a id="browser-text" class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img id="browser-text-img" src="img/safari.png" height="18" width="18"><span>Browser</span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="browser" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/10/Internet_Explorer_7_Logo.png/64px-Internet_Explorer_7_Logo.png" height="18" width="18">IE</a>

        </li>
        <li>

        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="browser" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/images/tech/278-opera-10.5.png" height="18" width="18">OPERA</a>

        </li>

        <li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /btn-group -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this changes the image but text is not working `$("#browser-text").text( $(this).text());` when i removed setting text image will draw.but how can i draw image with text.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$('a.browser').click( function() { 

      $("#browser-text").text( $(this).text());//this execute successfully.
      $('#browser-text img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    } );
```

Comment: when i removed `$("#browser-text").text( $(this).text());` this works.but how can i set text also.

Comment: @gihan check this new address in fiddle. i have changed it a little **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/abfqf1L2/

Comment: thanks its work charm.the problem was in `<a>` text i used with out `span tag` but with `span` tag like you did its works.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` — this is `<a>` tag, not `<img>`.

Try: `$('#browser-text img').attr('src', $('img', this).attr('src'));`